# How to prevent looping dropzone success event

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I think this is just a little problem, but I have no idea to do this, I've been figure it out for many sites, but has no result.

The question is, when I'm upload multiple with Dropzone by Meno http://www.dropzonejs.com/

then when upload success, I want to show alert that file has been uploaded,

```
myDropzone.on('success', function(file, response) {
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    console.log('Upload Success');
});
```

console log looping by each item, when I upload 10 items, then console.log loop 10 times, I want the console log only appear once, anyway anyone know how to handle this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropzonejs also has a success callback for multiple uploaded files: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-successmultiple

You can change your event listeners to use `successmultiple`:

```
myDropzone.on('successmultiple', function(file, response) {
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
    console.log('Upload Success');
});
```

Comment: OMFG, You are my real MVP brother! Thanks ;)